# htaccess redirect in limesurvey one survey to another

Tags: php, apache, http, .htaccess, redirect

i would like to redirect my.subdomain.eu/index.php?sid=34588&lang=de to my.subdomain.eu/index.php?sid=12345&lang=de.

i tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 http://my.subdomain.eu/index.php?sid=34588&lang=de http://my.subdomain.eu/index.php?sid=12345&lang=de
```

but it did not work. Any ideas what i did wrong?

Thanks,

Nils

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to not include your domain in the first part :

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /index.php?sid=34588&lang=de http://my.subdomain.eu/index.php?sid=12345&lang=de
```

But then, depending on your architecture, you might need to set a condition to match your subdomain with `RewriteCond`  and a `RewriteRule`

Comment: Hi Tsadiq, unfortunatly this did not work. I don't get the RewriteCond and RewriteRule tutorials, there are so many things to consider. E.g. i don't know which characters i have to mark with a "\" so it works. 

Isn't there an easy way to replace the string "34588" with "12345"?